# Is there any tool to create live styles for complex controls in wpf (xaml)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, blend

I am trying to style some complex controls in WPF (XAML)

I want a tool that I can use a default style and start changing it and make it useful for my application, but I can not find any such tools.

I tried to manually manipulate a style but it is very time consuming and I am not sure what style should I change to get the required output (for example, when I was trying to change the foreground of a header in a data grid, I wasted several hours to find what style should be changed to change the foreground colour)

Is there any such tool available?

What is the easiest way to find and change the style for complex controls such as data grid?

I tried Blend, but I could not understand how to work with it. It is very similar to visual studio and I could not find any section that relates to styling.

Comment: this question is totally off-topic here, and it even contains the answer on its own: Blend.

Comment: @Bizhan: thanks, can you help me to find a tutorial that explains how I can change the style of a data grid?  I can not find any step by step tutorial about this.

Comment: this blog post has described it all: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jaimer/2009/01/20/styling-microsofts-wpf-datagrid/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is *Blend*

---

You can read this blog post to know about DataGrid styling in **WPF**:

[Styling Microsoft’s WPF datagrid](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jaimer/2009/01/20/styling-microsofts-wpf-datagrid/) by Jaime Rodriguez

And you can read this article to learn about DataGrid styling in **Blend**:

[Using Datagrid in Expression Blend](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cd80b9/using-datagrid-in-expression-blend/) by Manoj Singh Panwar

---

You can always refer to [WPF docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/designers/designing-xaml-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2017) for more details (for both XAML designer or Blend)

---

There are tons of other tutorials as well such as:

[WPF DataGrid Customization using Style and Template](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/586132/%2FArticles%2F586132%2FWPF-DataGrid-Custommization-using-Style-and-Templa) by Hiren Khirsaria

[WPF Tutorial - WPF DataGrid Control](https://www.wpftutorial.net/datagrid.html)